# Nicolaus Mercator's extension of logarithmic power series from $(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion

I was reading this [Quora answer](https://qr.ae/pG9OjJ) in which the expansion of $\log(1+x)$ was extended in such a way that one could approximate any real number's natural logarithm quickly. The following was written in the answer as an identity:

$$ \ln(Z) - \ln(z)= 2 \left[ Q+ \frac{1}{3} Q^3... O(Q^5) \right] \tag{1}$$

With $Q = \frac{Z-z}{Z+z}$

How do we derive $(1)$ starting from :  $\ln(1+x) = x- \frac{x^2}{2!} +O(x^3)$? In the post it is mentioned that is done by $x= \frac{X-1}{X+1}$.. I suppose you put $X= \frac{Z}{z}$ but I can't see how the even powers on left side cancel and how one will get $\ln(Z) - \ln(z)$ on LHS.

---

It maybe noted that for finding $\ln(2), \ln(3)$ just by clever application of the formula.

### $\ln(2)$

$$ \ln(2) - \ln(1) \approx  2 \left[ \frac{1}{3} \right] = .66$$

### $\ln (3)$

$$ \ln(3) = \ln\left(2(1.5) \right)
= \ln(2) + \ln(1.5) = .66 + 2  \left[  \frac{1.5-1}{1.5+1}\right]=1.06$$

### $\ln(4)$

$\ln(4) = 2 \ln(2) \approx  1.32$

#### $\ln(5)$

$$ \ln(5) - \ln(4) \approx 2 \frac{1}{9} \approx  .\overline{22}$$

Hence, $\ln(5) \approx 1.54$

And so on with more clever manipulation.

Comment: Alternative approach, illustrated by example.  Assume that $\log(1 + x)$ can be approximated for $|x| < 1.$  Suppose that you want to approximate $\log(5)$.  Then this is equal to $(-1) \times \log(1/5)$, which can be approximated in the normal way.

Comment: $\log(1+x)$ has a much slower convergence compared to the scheme described here @user2661923  You may check that you need more than two terms for approximating $\ln 2$ while this series strikes in just one term.

Comment: Sure.  However, the advantage of my approach is that it is *mindless*.  That is, you don't need any analysis, you simply need to remember the trick of multiplying by $(-1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

For $|x|\lt 1$,

$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+O(x^5)$

and $\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+O(x^5)$

Subtract these to get: $\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=2(x+\frac{x^3}3+O(x^5))$

Put $x=Q$